# WordPress: Multiple conditional statements not working

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm trying a simple multiple conditional statement which should work fine with PHP but WordPress says no. What am I missing?

```
<?php if (is_page('sample1') || is_page('sample2') || is_page('sample3') ||     is_page('sample4')) { ?>
include this
<?php } else { ?>
include this instead
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When you say "WordPress says no", exactly what "no" is WordPress giving you? What happens if you're consistent with your php start tags? (i.e. use `<?php` instead of `<?` throughout)?

Comment: What does work or doesn't work? What do you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: Details Details. Post exact errors. Other than that, if wordpress says no, the only thing you can do is ask nicely.

Comment: Sorry, the inconsistency between <?php and <? was just for this example and something I forgot to put in.
What happens is I get this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function  is_page() in /home/b/clientname/www/wp-content/themes/clientname/footer.php on line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined function?

How are you calling footer.php from your theme?

Comment: @Adam's right - `footer.php` should be loaded by, and within, WordPress - sounds like you're trying to load it yourself, either outside WP, or before the function `is_page()` is available.

Comment: I was including the footer in a regular template. Think I solved the matter now, see below.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the code you posted.  It has everything to do with the path to the footer or where you are trying to load it within the page lifecycle.  Also check if the path is right.

Comment: I noticed now that I put a <? } ?> as closing tag instead of <?php } ?> for the whole statement and it's content. It works now. Shouldn't it have worked either way? I guess mixing <?php with <? can cause such problems.

Comment: Which tag you use should make no difference.  I have used both many times.  As long as they match, which one doesn't matter...unless you have your server config different or something odd is going on with the interpreter.